# Receiving Invalid character found in method name on GET request

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, https, mapbox

I'm trying to utilize a MapBox api in my backend, but am receiving this error. I've never seen this before. Is there something I need to do to configure my endpoint?

Error -

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name [0x160x030x010x020x000x010x000x010xfc0x030x03mA0xe8&0x1f0xfa80xcd0x1b0x900xec!0xfd0xb30x04<0xcb0xa20x16@0x96H0x180x88[0xf90xeb0xbeK?^0xc8]. HTTP method names must be tokens
```

Service -

```
public String getTarget() {
    TargetLocation location = targetLocationRepository.findTargetLocationById();
    String lat = location.getLatitude();
    String lng = location.getLongitude();
    return "https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/"+lat+","+lng+".json?access_token=${"+MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN+"}";
}
```

Controller -

```
@GetMapping(value = "getTarget")
public String getTarget() {
    return targetLocationService.getTarget();
}
```

Comment: The error says "method name", not "URL".   The method is typically GET, POST, etc., though extensions are possible.

Comment: @user16632363 It says "HTTP method names must be tokens" at the end of the error message. That's what is throwing me

Comment: Change the server port for your app server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this might be related to HTTPS. It occurs when you try to execute HTTPS request from client on endpoint that has not HTTPS enabled. Use `http:` (`http://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places`) in your client instead.

Comment: Strange as it's a 3rd party api, but I see you're right.

Answer (score -1):

The method is expecting you to use HTTP instead of HTTPS.